# How to return readonly fields?

Tags: c#, readonly

Error is

> "A readonly field cannot be assigned to(...)"

I must return vector, which equal sum of two another vectors (vector and vector1)
ReadOnlyVector has readonly fields X and Y. How can I initialize them and return new ReadOnlyVector?

```
public class ReadOnlyVector
    {
        public readonly double X;
        public readonly double Y;
        public ReadOnlyVector(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
        public ReadOnlyVector Add (ReadOnlyVector vector, ReadOnlyVector vector1)
        {           
            return new ReadOnlyVector {X = vector.X + vector1.X, Y = vector.Y + vector1.Y}  
        }             
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the constructor. You're currently using object initializer syntax.

```
public ReadOnlyVector Add (ReadOnlyVector vector, ReadOnlyVector vector1)
{           
    return new ReadOnlyVector(vector.X + vector1.X, vector.Y + vector1.Y);
}
```

Comment: I understand, it was only atempt because I didn't know syntax of this constructor. 10Q for you answer